# How to use or create a non-global javascript variable cache from a html accessible tag

Tags: javascript, html, scope, onkeyup

I have a javascript function that needs to be invoked 'onkeyup' from an input field:

```
<input id="searchSurname" type="text" name="surname" onkeyup="queryPatients()" />
```

Yet, for the life of the session (or so long as the user is using that page) the function needs to be able to cache some results from each time the event has happened.

In order to prevent my cache variables being globally accessible (nasty nasty) I enclose them in an anonymous function (a pattern I've seen quite a bit)

```
(function(){

    var cacheSurname = "";
    var cacheGivenNames = "";

    function queryPatients() {

        var surname = $('#searchSurname').val();
        var givenNames = $('#searchGivenNames').val();

        // do some more work, cache the variables 
        cacheSurname = surname;
        cacheGivenNames = givenNames;
    }   
}).call(this);
```

Yet, being so enclosed, my input field is unable to invoke the method.

Is there an appropriate solution? Or do I have to resort to a global variable after all?

Comment: you could use jquery to bind to the event.

Comment: ahh yes, I get you. So I would not HAVE to refer to the method from the HTML at all. Good, I'll try that and post my results here. Thanks!

Comment: hmm.. I feel almost like I'm in the twilight zone. Someone posted an answer which I was going to read up more about (using this.<variablename>  inside the function scope)  but the answer was deleted. Why? I'm pretty sure I didn't imagine it!

Comment: @DanielA.White I guess you have answered my question for me. Would you like to write it in "as" an answer so I can accept it? Or should I write up my own answer ? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery, you can bind to the key up event inside of that "private" scope.

```
(function(){

    var cacheSurname = "";
    var cacheGivenNames = "";

    function queryPatients() {

        var surname = $('#searchSurname').val();
        var givenNames = $('#searchGivenNames').val();

        // do some more work, cache the variables 
        cacheSurname = surname;
        cacheGivenNames = givenNames;
    } 
    $('#searchSurname').on('keyup', queryPatients);
}).call(this);
```